# from autoslug import AutoSlugField Not working

Tags: python, django

please I need help with Python Django stuff
I have installed `pip install pillow` and I need  to import it in models.py. When I run this code in command prompt, I get this error[At line:1 char:1

- from autoslug import AutoSlugField
- 

The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
ception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi4ao.jpg)

I am using Python 3.10 with Django 4.0.1 on Windows 10 64bits
I will appreciate your help to solve this

Comment: You're running that command in PowerShell, not a Python script/shell?

Comment: you seem to be using powershell instead of python interpreter, this question is not even valid question.

Answer (score 0):

Please open python shell first, and there try your code.
**python manage.py shell**

Comment: Thanks but not working    


>>> python manage.py shell
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python manage.py shell
           ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>